# Should I use simple past tense or "could" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> Reading, watching TV, even being online made Mary's eyelids weight a
>   ton. Only one activity **kept/could keep** her senses alert: talking
>   to John.

What's the correct option and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kept - something which was done already and it is not active now
could keep - something which she should have done before and need to follow in the future

Out of these two `could have` will be suitable.

"will keep" will enrich the sentence even more.